# Apply Foreign key in phpmyadmin 4.1.14

Tags: phpmyadmin

I am using phpmyadmin 4.1.14 and I want to apply foreign key. But it doesn't display link for relation view, how can I do that?

Comment: Do you have index on that column?

Answer (score 0):

You can create foreign keys manually in PHPMYAdmin, just as you would in SQL.

`CREATE TABLE Orders
(
O_Id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
OrderNo int NOT NULL,
P_Id int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Persons(P_Id)
)`

Answer (score 0):

If you need to create any foreign key for any field, Must you need to create a index for that particular field. After you can apply foreign key.

`ALTER TABLE`table_name`ADD INDEX (`field_name`) ;`

Now you can see in Relation View. Than you can apply foreign key